# SwipeListview close opened items not working on multi choice mode

Tags: android

This is about the SwipeListView [Library](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) by 47deg.

In my swipe list view I have enabled multi-choice mode and made so that only one row can be opened at a time. The problem occurs when I open a row and try to enter multi-choice mode by long pressing another row (the row previously opened stays opened). I am calling `swiplelistview.closeOpenedItems()` in `onPrepareActionMode()` and it seems to be doing nothing. Is there any way I can make the entire swipelistview to reset to its original state before entering multi-choice mode

Comment: i have the exact same problem. =\

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding it in a different thread? But i am not sure if it's the correct way.

```
            layout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        swiplelistview.closeOpenedItems()
                    }
                }, 100);
            }
```